# Adding components to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I have a JFrame in which constructor I call initComponents() generated by Netbeans. It initializes the GUI created in Netbean's design editor. After that I create a new JLabel and call content.add(label) where content is a JPanel which is visible. Next I call validate(). The JLabel won't appear. What's wrong?

Comment: What `LayoutManager` are you using?  The default layout manager used by NetBeans is the `Freeform` layout manager. It was designed to used by the form editor and was not designed to be used by hand. It's possible that with the lack of constraints, your label is simply been ignored

Comment: Could be any number of things. Can you post your code?

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer! I changed the LayoutManager and it started working :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Please enter that as an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see you saw the comment now deleted.  If you had read it carefully, you might have noticed the comment about 'snippets'.  Anything less than the full code is no more than a 'bunch of snippets' - approximately as useless as just one snippet.  Try reading ***all*** the comment, for better understanding.

Comment: I understand perfectly. We all should use common sense here. When someone says 'post code' this should entail using the _relevant_ sections

Comment: @AndrewThompson Consider it done 8D

Comment: @Reimeus  If someone does not know what is wrong with code, how do they know which sections are relevant to the bug?  In a question like this, the OP would generally show the `actionPerformed()`  that adds a new label to the panel.  But that does not explain if for example, a) the control that is supposed to invoke the action ever had a listener attached b) The layout of the container (which would generally have been set in the constructor or `initComponments()`.  Both of these things might be relevant to the problem.  An SSCCE guarantees not only 'short', but that all relevant code is present

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes SSCCE is the ideal and I never said NOT to use this. You _assumed_ that I was implying to post all of the code and this does make posts extremely unreadable & cluttered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What LayoutManager are you using?

The default layout manager used by NetBeans is the Freeform layout manager.

It was designed to used by the form editor and was not designed to be used by hand.

It's possible that with the lack of constraints, your label is simply been ignored

Comment: +1, since this solved the issue for the OP as written in comments :-)